# Entity Framework, Connection String throws formatexception

Tags: entity-framework, connection-string

I am Using Entity Framework 6.1.1

I have a class in one project, which include FBuyShopContext, another for models, and one Asp project with MVC 5

In my first project I have following

```
public class FBuyShopContext : DbContext
{
    public FBuyShopContext()
        : base("name=FBuyShopContext")
    {
    }


    public virtual DbSet<Product> Admins { get; set; }
}
```

}

And a Product Model in a other Library project

```
public class Product
{
    public Product()
    {}

    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

my connection string is following

```
 <connectionStrings>
<add name="FBuyShopContext" connectionString="data source=tschikovani\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=OnlineShop;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

and when I want to add a new product into database in my controller

```
FBuyShopContext db = new FBuyShopContext();
Product new = new Product ();
new.Name = "Iphone";
db.Products.Add(new);
db.SaveChanges();
```

I have a following exception

```
An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll
keyword not supported: 'data source'.
```

Why this happened? connection string is fully right

Answer (score 0):

I can see three things going on here:

1) `DbContext`'s contructor should take the name of the connection string, therefore change it to just `FBuyShopContext` and not `name=FBuyShopContext`.

```
 public class FBuyShopContext : DbContext
 {
      public FbuyShopContext() : base("FBuyShopContext") {}
 }
```

2) Your connection string ends with a `&quot;`, which is an invalid character. You should remove it.

3) You should specify your **primary key** on the model, either using the fluent API, or by data annotations:

```
 public class Product {
      [Key]
      public int Id { get; set; }

      [Required]
      public string Name { get; set; }
 }
```

I'm pretty sure the error you are getting is caused by 2), but 1) and 3) would have caused you problems later.

Comment: I Removed &quot; but nothing changed, I have exception still

Comment: @needermen Is it the same exception? Did you also fixed 1) and 3)?

Comment: Yes, it's same exception, Of Course I also fixed 1 and 3

Comment: Try changing `data source` to `Data Source` (note it's capitalized). Do the same with `initial catalog` (change it to `Initial Catalog`), and with other similar properties you may encounter

Comment: Would you mind posting the whole configuration file? Omitting irrelevant sections such as aplication keys